# Converting Mysqli_query to string for use in hashing

Tags: php, hash, mysqli

I have a simple login script that is causing me some trouble. This piece of code is run once the user input has been validated:

```
$salt = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT salt FROM members WHERE Email='$email'");
$salt1 = $salt;//I'm not sure of the need for this line.
$hash = sha1($salt1 , $pass);
```

This code takes the salt from the database and then hashes the inputed password with it in order to check the password against the database. The problem I am having is this:

```
Warning: sha1() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given...
```

How can I convert the query to a string. I know I'm using sha1, but that's only temporary. Am I doing something very dumb; I've only recently been getting back into PHP so does anyone know what to do?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the result from your query so you can use it as an array.

```
$query= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT salt FROM members WHERE Email='$email'"); 
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$salt = $row['salt'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that an SQL query, as performed by `mysqli_query`, may return more than one row in the result. You can retrieve the contents of these rows by calling [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) or similar.

Also, beware SQL injection. The query you are currently performing is vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. May I ask how to implement that, as when I do `$salt1 = mysqli_stmt_fetch($salt);`, I get the error `Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this , simplt replace this

```
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($salt); // fetch the array

$salt1 = $row['salt']; 

$hash = sha1($salt1 , $pass);  // encrypt
```